# Is Bluetooth SIG qualification required for an iOS app that uses Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am building an iPhone app that uses Bluetooth to communicate with a remote sensor. The peripheral is a Bluetooth bicycle speed sensor. The app uses info form the peripheral device to calculate distance traveled.

I see there is a Bluetooth Special Interest Group (SIG) that is responsible for ensuring that manufacturers comply with Bluetooth license agreements and technical standards

Do these standards and qualification requirements apply to phone apps?
Does an app developer need to pursue approvals?
If so - how does an individual, a non-corporate developer, get membership in order to purse qualification.

I have tried to reach the Bluetooth SIG by phone without success. 
There does not seem to be any way for non-corporations to communicate with them.

Thanks
J.Day

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Paulw11 any citation to support that? I'm interested in this question as well. But I need something more than "a comment on SE said so" :)

Comment: Because you are using hardware and software from others (e,g. Apple and Nordic) you are not creating your own Bluetooth hardware or software stack. Even if you were the Bluetooth SIG is not responsible for verifying conformance. It establishes standards for conformance;  if you were creating your own hardware (at the radio level) it is actually the FCC and their counterparts in each country that you would need to get certification (via a 3rd party lab)

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Bluetooth Support about this issue and got the following reply:

> Thanks for contacting us. Could you please confirm which GATT Based Profile your product implements and the role? This can help us determine if your application fits this definition. In most cases, smartphone applications use the smartphone OS' SDK/API and do not implement new or extra Bluetooth functionality. In these cases Qualification is not required or possible.
>
> A common example for not needing qualification is a user interface
> (UI) application created for a smartphone. If the application is using
> the smartphone's SDK/API and not implementing any extra Bluetooth
> functionality then no new Declaration is required.

Comment: This is incredibly misleading. You do not need anything from the Bluetooth SIG to use Core Bluetooth. I have built certified Bluetooth products for years, and belong to a SIG organization. They're not talking about apps. The page you've linked is the "Bluetooth Module Vendor Qualification Guide." In this context, "software" is a Bluetooth *stack* (i.e. if you were writing Core Bluetooth itself, not using it). Please delete this. I almost never downvote, but this answer is going to confuse people.